# Angular JS - Update Scope value on click

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Right now I am passing my parameter through the state like:

```
        .state('app.listing', {
        url: '/ad/listing/:adId/{type}',
        params: {
          adId: {
            value: "adId",
            squash: false
          }, type: {
            value: null,
            squash: true
          }
        },
```

This works as I can get "type" from $stateParams and update my get request.

Is there not a way to do this from a click event and not use $stateParams for passing the "type" param?

I basically have a button that filters results and passes the type param from the button.  It would be a lot easier if I can just attach a click event to it which then updates my get request.

Just messing around I tried doing something like

```
  $scope.filter = function(type) {
    if(type) {
      return type;
    }
    return '' ;
  }

    $scope.type = $scope.filter();
```

Service is like

```
$http.get(API_ENDPOINT.url + '/listing/' + adId, {
        params: {
          page: page,
          type: type // essentially $scope.type 
        },
      }).
```

and then on my button I have

```
 <button ng-click="filter('2')"></button>
```

^ This will pass 2 for type, but won't reinit the http get call on click. Do I need to broadcast the change is there a simple way to do this?

Does this even make sense?  The code above is just mock to give an idea, but open to suggestions if any.

Comment: Do you call the `$http.get(...)` in the filter function?

Comment: Have you tried $state.go('app.listing', { type: $scope.type })?

Comment: @k4l4m Well,  its tied into a more complex setup, the http is tied into an init function which then further goes into an infiniteScroll and pagination process.  I tried re-initing the init function from the filter function, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Angular never requires you to make `broadcasts` to reflect changes made to `scope`variables via the controller

```
var typeWatcher = '1';
$scope.filter = function(type){

    if (type !== typeWatch)
        {

            $http.get(API_ENDPOINT.url + '/listing/' + adId, {
               params: {
                  page: page,
                  type: type // essentially $scope.type 
              },
           });
           typeWatcher = type;
        }

};
```

Comment: Yeah but how to reinit the $http service after the change is where I am stuck. I tried also using $scope.$watch() for change events, but that also didn't work.  My current init on load is utilizing infiniteScroll which has all the http calls.  I guess I was basically wanting to just have http update based on $scope change.

Comment: @limit On ngclick check for the value if the value has changed then call the service

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your get call in a function & call it after the filter function in `ng-click`

```
$scope.functionName = function () {
  return $http.get(API_ENDPOINT.url + '/listing/' + adId, {
    params: {
      page: page,
      type: type // essentially $scope.type 
    }
  })
}
```

then in HTML

```
<button ng-click="filter('2'); functionName()"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, To call `$http.get` method on click,

```
$scope.filter = function(type) {
  if(type) {
    //call the method using service.methodName
    return type;
  }
  return '' ;
}
```

and wrap that $http.get method to one function.

Hope it helps you.

Cheers